# How to transfer 6 TB files using SCP?

Tags: centos6, centos7, scp

I have 2 Linux Centos Servers.

The First one is 6.7 and the second one is 7.

How can I transfer all files and folders from `/home/sv1/public_html` from server 1 to `/home/sv2/public_html` in server 2 ?

The data is 6TB and I can't move them using FTP.

Thanks

Comment: For that large of a transfer using a copy that can be restarted would be preferable. `rsync` is a common copy that has that characteristic while `scp` does not.

Comment: a friend of mine suggested SCP and he said the copy would be perfect and no files would be damaged using SCP but I consider rsync too . thanks for the answer

Comment: @AliMastermovie Data corruption in such a transfer depends more on the hardware you are using than the software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use rsync in server1

```
rsync -dr /home/sv1/public_html -e ssh user@server2:/home/sv2/public_html -v
```

This will take a while since it's 6GB. You should consider using `screen` and keep it working while you aren't active on the server.

Comment: thanks for the answer . the data is 6 TB not GB . any how by user@server2 you mean root@ip ? BTW I want the files to remain on the first server after moving . Is that ok ?

Comment: You are copying into the home directory of sv2, so say `sv2@ip`. The files will remain. Use `screen` so as to keep it working in background

Comment: should the destination server have port 22 ? It's now set on different ssh port .

Comment: Without specifying the port, ssh is taking the default port which is 22. If you are having it on another port like 50 then your command goes `rsync -dr /home/sv1/public_html -e ssh -p 50 user@server2:/home/sv2/public_html -v`

Comment: ok the tansfer began , I didn't use screen command but I increased SSH timeout to 999999999 . Will this be ok ?

Comment: I suggested the screen in case you encounter connection issues, you may lost connection to server1 if its not a physical server. But if it is, then you're good :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a user on server2 with suitable privilege and the user1 on server1 having a suitable private key: on server1.

```
cd /home/sv2/public_html
scp -i /home/user1/.ssh/keyfile user@server1:/home/sv1/public_html .
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using rsync, as it's more convenient for transfering such big amount of data, especially because rsync can continue partially transfered files (e.g. in case of network timeout).

`rsync -avzP /home/sv1/public_html/ -e ssh user@server2:/home/sv2/public_html/`

**-a** - archive mode (preserves permissions, ownership, etc.)

**-v** - prints verbose transfer status

**-z** - on-the-fly compression for faster transfer

**-P** - keeps partially transfered files in order to resume the transfer where it broke the last time.

Comment: `-z` option would actually be counterproductive since he is transferring data over LAN.

Comment: I agree, but I don't see anyone mentioning LAN :-)